# Date time-starting a new day at 3:00 am

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a code that analyzes behavior of users on a certain web site, it uses many of `DateTime` functions. Now, I want to start a new day from `3:00 am` instead of `12:00 am` as it is in the default however I really don't want to change any other part of the code.

For example: say I have a `DateTime` like `2014-08-27t02:59:00` and than I do `AddMinutes(2)`, the date should change to `2014-08-28t03:01:00`.

Is there any method to set the "new days beginning" without changing the other functions?

Comment: I doubt it's doable using just what's in .NET already. Just for fun, try this thought experiment. Say that you have a DateTime instance representing (let's ignore time zones) 2014-08-27T02:59:00. Then you call AddMinutes(2) on it. Is the return value of that call 2014-08-27T03:01:00 (because you added two minutes), or 2014-08-28T03:01:00 (because you crossed the "day change time")? You could probably wrap a DateTime in something else and turn it into something useful for your purposes, but you'd need to define things like that.

Comment: If it's possible to do, you'll likely be losing 3 hours from every day. Is that acceptable for your problem? Does it matter that you will lose 3 hours from every day?

Comment: the idea is that every day still will be 24 hours, but it will start from 3 am, for example if i have a date time 2014-08-27T02:59:00 and than i do AddMinutes(2), the date will change to 2014-08-28T03:01:00.

Comment: Interesting problem. Perhaps [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) could help here, but I am not enough expert in that

Comment: Can you just use timezones or something?

Comment: I would probably just use regular DateTime, and then when ever I needed to show the date (or export it), use an extension method that would do the change needed (if dt.Hour < 3 dt = dt.AddDays(-1) simplified)

Comment: Definitely agree with @SteenT - don't conflate *presentation* requirements with the actual reality. The dates change at Midnight. if you want to change how a date is *displayed* to users somewhere, deal with that as a presentation function.

Comment: What on earth would require this behavior? Maybe set the server clock back 3 hours ;p

Comment: Your dates will have `2014-08-28t02:00:00` > `2014-08-28t04:00:00`. That's weird. I definitely agree with @Chris - you should use time zones or something (but I think that also isn't a trivial task with `DateTime`).

Comment: Why would you want this? Could you please clarify for a curious mind as to why? :P

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm not sure that's just presentation. You want to ask questions like "Which 10 users were the most active on 2014-08-28?". The definition of a day affects your analysis. This is pretty similar to business quarters, where some companies end/start the quarters at odd dates (e.g. first quarter starts at December 28).

Comment: @Kobi: I would agree to a certain extent. Although not just for presentation I would be inclined to have a "ReportingDate" and a function that gets a reporting date and returns just a date that would then be used for aggregation and display. I might even be inclined to create my own object that wraps a DateTime just so I could guarantee never to get them confused.

Comment: its exactly as @Kobi described,its more correct to say that a user that started he's session on 25th of July 00:20 was actually active on the 24th of July and not the 25th.

Comment: Are you doing this because of East coast / West coast thing? if so, don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `BCL` date handling no, I did a read through NodaTime's documentation and couldn't find anything there as well.

Without knowing to much about how your code works right now I would recommend you to go with either of the following ideas; create an extension method for getting the "correct" date (in your model) or create a new date-class for your purposes.

Extension-method:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
  public static DateTime GetDay(this DateTime date)
  {
    return date.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.FromHours(3) ? date.Date : date.AddDays(-1).Date;
  }
}
```

Or create your own type, `MyDateTime`, which works the way you want it to. Exactly what you need I do not know, but getting all the "normal" `DateTime` methods working required quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [custom timezone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb309898(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var displayName = "(GMT+03:00) Custom/Maxim Dunavicher Time";
var standardName = "Maxim Dunavicher Time"; 
var offset = new TimeSpan(03, 00, 00);

var tz = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(
    standardName, offset, displayName, standardName);
```

You calculate everything using UTC. But you display using that new time zone.